# Javascript: reload page at specified time

Tags: javascript

I have a program which periodically writes an html page as a local file, which is displayed in a browser. I'd like the page to refresh at specified times.

The program rewrites the file, especially the Initial text and the targetDate.

I tried just using META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300", but that would drift over time. That's why I'd prefer specifying the reload time.

I'm not running a server, all this is client side.

The following is not working (it does not relaod at the specified time. How can change it so that it does reload at the specified time?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Initial text
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
var targetDate==new Date();
targetDate.setDate(myDate.getDate(2013, 5, 20, 8, 16));

function myTimer()
{
var d=new Date();
if (d>=targetDate) {
     location.reload(true)
     }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Have you broken it? PS: you would better use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` with 1 second period

Comment: It's not reloading at the specified time.  I'd set the interval in minutes, but have been using seconds for testing.

Comment: where did you get this code? Do you realize what this code does?

Comment: `Date#setDate` sets the day of the month. Try `new Date("03/22/2013 12:13:14")`

Comment: @zerkms I wrote it myself. It should set a target time, then every second check if the current time is after the target time. When that condition is met, it should reload.

Comment: @foosion: what do you think `targetDate` equals to? Have you checked it? Where `myDate` comes from?

Comment: @zerkms: I think targetDate equals May 20, 2013 at 8:16am local time. How would I check it?  I'll revise to reflect Bart's comment and try again

Comment: @foosion: `console.log(varname);` and look at the console. "I think" --- in programming it's common to follow the facts, not beliefs

Comment: Memo to self, consider learning enough javascript to be familiar with console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var targetDate = new Date(2013, 4, 20, 8, 16);
setInterval(function () {
    if (new Date().getTime() >= targetDate.getTime()) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Couple issues in the pasted code.. I refactored a bit for simplicity. Key issue though, is that the javascript Date object has zero-based months. So if you wanted that comparison to trigger 'now' you need to use a 4 for the month.

Also, I tend to do time comparisons with getTime(). Kind of a habit but not a 'real issue' in your code.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. For intervals longer than 1 second, would I make any changes other than increase the 1000 milliseconds?

Comment: Nope. Just change the interval timeout to whatever you need and it'll work.

Comment: Actually it makes no sense to use `setInterval` here, but `setTimeout`

Comment: It makes sense if the target date changes, which was my assumption given the reference to a myDate variable. zerkms is correct though, if this is going to execute at a single, specific known time.

If the intent is to continually evaluate the state though, setInterval is indeed the right method to use

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="300"? If so, I'm concerned about "drift". With using this refresh, after many rounds, it is no longer reloading at an even multiple of 300 seconds.

Comment: @stirno, the page is rewritten frequently. I'd like it to reload, for example, at 12:00, 12:05, 12:10, ...  With the meta-refresh, it would drift off to 1:06, ... 2:08, ... I'm guessing setTimeout will have the same problem

Comment: @foosion: there is no any problem. Just calculate a correct interval and use it with `setInterval`